# How to serialize fields related to a model through another model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My models are as follows:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content


class OptionGroup(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(
        'Question',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default='',
        )

    options = models.ManyToManyField('Option')


class Option(models.Model):

    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        )
```

I am trying to create a Question serializer which will serializer Question.content and all the related Option.content without displaying any fields from OptionGroup. How do I do this?

Comment: why you are using OptionGroup ? you can put options in `Question` model

Comment: There are some other fields on OptionGroup which I've omitted for simplicity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a SerializerMethod field and define it accordingly:

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from diagnosisApp.models import Question, Option


class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = ('id', 'content')


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    options = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('content', 'options')

    def get_options(self, obj):
        selected_options = Option.objects.filter(
            optiongroup__question=obj).distinct()
        return OptionSerializer(selected_options, many=True).data
```

Answer (score 6):

You can serialize related models by using nested serializers like this:

```
class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = ('content',)

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    options = OptionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('content', 'options')
```

Which will give the following result:

```
{
    'content': 'some content',  # your Question
    'options': [
        {'content': 'some content'},  # related Option
        {'content': 'some other content'},  # related Option
        ...
    ],
}
```

You can read more about nested serializers [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

Comment: Have you seen the model structure? Option is not directly related to Question. It doesn't work for me like that.

Answer (score 0):

models:

```
class OptionGroup(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(
        'Question',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default='',
        related_name='question_options'
        )

    options = models.ManyToManyField('Option')

class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        )
    # options = models.ManyToManyField('Option', through='OptionGroup')
    def get_options(self):
        options = self.question_options.all().values('options')
        option_ids = []
        for option in options:
            option_ids.append(option['options'])
        return Option.objects.filter(id__in=option_ids)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

class Option(models.Model):

    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

serializers

```
class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Option
        exclude = ('id',)


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    options = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_options(self, obj):
        options = obj.get_options()
        return OptionSerializer(options, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Lots of errors in your answer. You declared `OptionSerializer` but did not use it. You're using a field `question_options` but it is not defined on that particular model (assuming you meant `optiongroup_set`). But still after correcting those, it is still not in the format I want. The format I want is what @Stevy above gave but his answer is wrong too since option is not directly related to question.